# Prevent authentication dialog in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, basic-authentication

I have a REST API that uses basic authentication. There's a web client, that sends the `Authorization` header manually using `XmlHttpRequest` to prevent the common issues with basic authentication, like no logout. Everything works fine, as long as web client and REST API are on two different origins.

However, if they're deployed on the same origin, Chrome shows the basic authentication dialog. Is there any way to prevent this while having them on the same origin?